Permission Error (EPERM) When Installing Node.js Packages with Npm
When running npm install in my React project, I encounter errors, often with the message EPERM: operation not permitted. The error messages usually indicate that npm is unable to remove or modify certain directories or files within the node_modules directory. This error is preventing me from installing and running my project.

Rebooting: I've restarted my computer multiple times, but the problem persists.
Running as Administrator: I ran all commands with administrative privileges.
Reinstalling Node.js: I reinstalled Node.js and npm.
Deleting node_modules: I tried deleting the node_modules folder and the package-lock.json file, but sometimes I couldn't delete them, or I got a permission error.

Detailed error messages: EPERM: operation not permitted, rmdir [path/to/folder]
Environment:

Operating System: Windows 10
Node.js Version: v20.12.2

What could be causing these permission-related problems? How can I resolve file locking or permission errors like these? What other steps would you recommend to fix this problem?
